# How to Convert List of Folders and SubFolder into JSOn FOrmat

Tags: java, json

i want to populate Folder Name With Sub Folder name on KendoDrop Down . so i want to Convert Folder Directory in JSOn Format How can i Do That ?

```
public class FolderPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File currentDir = new File("Folder URL "); // current directory
        displayDirectoryContents(currentDir);

    }
    public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {

        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("[");
        try {

            File[] files = dir.listFiles();

            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    sb1 = sb1.append("{\"JSONKEY\":\"" + file.getCanonicalPath() + "\"},");
                    String str = file.getCanonicalPath();
                    displayDirectoryContents(file);

                } else {
                }

            }
            sb1.deleteCharAt(sb1.length() - 1);
            sb1 = sb1.append("]");
            System.out.println("s2==>" + sb1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Here i am Not Getting Full Directroy into JSOn Please Help

Comment: Since i am New Here So please Help !!!

Comment: what is the json format you expect?

Comment: make the main folder as json object and subfolders as json array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `StringBuilder` object on each iteration. That's why your concatenation does not work.

Consider the contents of you `C:\test` is composed of 3 directories:

```
c:\test
  |
  +--css
  |   +--less
  +--js
```

The code below, returns:

```
 [{"JSONKEY":"C:\test\css"},
  {"JSONKEY":"C:\test\css\less"},
  {"JSONKEY":"C:\test\js"}]
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FolderPath {

    private static FileFilter onlyDirectories = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isDirectory();
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File currentDir = new File("C:\\test"); // current directory
        displayDirectoryContents(currentDir);
    }

    public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("[");
        doDisplayDirectoryContents(dir, sb1);
        if (sb1.length() > 1) {
            sb1.deleteCharAt(sb1.length() - 1);
        }
        sb1.append("]");
        System.out.println(sb1);
    }

    private static void doDisplayDirectoryContents(File dir, StringBuilder sb1) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(onlyDirectories);

        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                try {
                    sb1.append("{\"JSONKEY\":\"" + file.getCanonicalPath() + "\"},");
                    doDisplayDirectoryContents(file, sb1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: really Great Post and Thanks for revert Back With Quick response

Comment: can you implement on my Code please ? Thanks in advance

Comment: can any one implement my Code According to question . ??

Comment: @KaranSingh I gave you an answer based on the code from your question. It does what you asked. What do you really want?

Comment: @  Jose Rui Santos : Sorry Sir But can you modify my code please .  the problem with my code is .i am not able to get sunFolder name in JSON Format . better you can test and please Sir post updated Code .like i got only c:\test\css not able to get less According to your Path Graph
  |
  +--css
  |   +--less
  +--js. Thanks in advance

Comment: @  Jose Rui Santos: i want only on single method code will work properly. if you modify my code then it would be better for me .

Comment: @KaranSingh Sorry, but my code works properly. I tested. If you run **my** code, you will get all folders, regardless of their deep level.

Comment: @ Jose Rui Santos: ok Sir can you Make one Common method on your Programe like  After class you create method Jose() that will close before class .

Comment: @KaranSingh You mean, something like `String folders = FolderPath.get("c:\\test");` ?

Comment: No Sir . like previously you create Four Method : FileFilter ,main,displayDirectoryContents,doDisplayDirectoryContents, So i want one more Simple method like : public void Jose () that is start after class and close before class .

Answer (score -2):

```
public List<Object> getDirectoryContents(String path) throws IOException {
    File directory = new File(path);
    File[] files;
enter code here    FileFilter fileFilter = file -> file.isDirectory() || file.isFile();
    files = directory.listFiles(fileFilter);
    List<Object> directoryContent = new ArrayList<>();
    if(files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File filename = files[i];
            String folderPath[] =filename.toString().split("/");
            if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                Folder folder = new Folder();
                folder.setName(folderPath[folderPath.length - 1]);
                folder.setType("folder");
                folder.setChildren(mapper.readTree(mapper.writeValueAsString(getDirectoryContents(path + "/" + folder.getName()))));
                directoryContent.add(folder);
            }
            else{
                Files file = new Files();
                file.setName(folderPath[folderPath.length - 1]);
                file.setType("file");
                directoryContent.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    return directoryContent;
}
```

public class Files {

```
private String name;
private String type = "file";
```

}

public class Folder {

```
private String name;
private String type = "folder";
private JsonNode children;
```

}